# Implementing hci - creating conncetion in bluetooth

Tags: bluez

> The attached C++ code succeeds in hci_create_connection, but fails 
>   hci_authenticate_link

```
int Connection = hci_create_connection(dev_descriptor, &bdaddr, htobs(ptype), 0, 0,
        &handle, 0);

int authenticate = hci_authenticate_link(dev_descriptor, handle, 0);
```

Since I am missing descriptions of both of these function I am asking

1. Does hci_create_connection  creates connection between local processor and local Bluetooth device and NOT between local Bluetooth and remote Bluetooth device ?
2. hci_authenticate_link - what is this "link" referring to  - assuming  term link implies something between point A and point B .

Both of these function are one of the initial / first hci function I am using to establish connection between local (Raspberry Pi ) and remote (PC) via Bluetooth.

I am guessing they are part of the connection / relation between local processor and NOT even close to establish real connection between local and remote Bluetooth devices. 
I am assuming I better have "local" connection working / verified before I even start looking for the "nearby Bluetooth devices ".